# Find the radius $r$ of the semicircumference below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure, if $PF=3$, $OP=1$, calculate "$r$".

Answer by plan geometry

[image]

I try

[image]

$FM \cdot FN = FA\cdot FB$

$FA =4 - r$

$\therefore (4-r)\cdot(FB) = FM\cdot FN \implies (4-r)\cdot(4-r+2r) = FM\cdot FN$

$\therefore 16-r^2=FM\cdot FN$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your diagram with a couple of lines, a point and several line lengths added:

[image: Diagram of OP with a couple of lines, a point and several line lengths added]

In particular, $LF$ and $LO$ have been added, with $\lvert FL\rvert = a$. Since $LM$ and $LN$ are tangent to the circle, then $LO$ is a perpendicular bisector of $MN$, intersecting at $Q$, with $\lvert LQ\rvert = b$, $\lvert MQ\rvert = \lvert QN\rvert = c$ and $\lvert QO\rvert = d$. Finally, $\lvert FM\rvert = e$ and $\lvert LP\rvert = h$.

Since $\lvert FP\rvert = 3$, we have using the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle FLP$ and $\triangle FLQ$ that

$$a^2 = 9 + h^2 = (e + c)^2 + b^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also, since $\lvert PO\rvert = 1$, the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle PLO$ gives

$$1 + h^2 = (b + d)^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Subtracting \eqref{eq2A} from \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$8 = (e^2 + 2ec + c^2 + b^2) - (b^2 + 2bd + d^2) = e^2 + 2ec + c^2 - 2bd - d^2 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

We have $\angle LNQ + \angle NLQ = \angle LNQ + \angle QNO = 90^{\circ} \;\;\to\;\; \angle NLQ = \angle QNO$. Thus, $\triangle NQL \sim \triangle OQN$ so

$$\frac{\lvert LQ\rvert}{\lvert QN\rvert} = \frac{\lvert QN\rvert}{\lvert QO \rvert} \;\;\to\;\; \frac{b}{c} = \frac{c}{d} \;\;\to\;\; bd = c^2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$8 = e^2 + 2ec - c^2 - d^2 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

From your result, and my line lengths, we have

$$16 - r^2 = \lvert FM\rvert \cdot \lvert FN\rvert = e(e + 2c) = e^2 + 2ec \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Using this, and the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle OQN$ giving that $c^2 + d^2 = r^2$, in \eqref{eq5A} produces

$$8 = (16 - r^2) - r^2 \;\;\to\;\; 2r^2 = 8 \;\;\to\;\; r = 2 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Comment: I posted a "very simple" solution using quadruple harmonic.

Comment: @petaarantes You're welcome for the help. Re: your "very simple" solution, it's great you determined it, but I'm unclear about how you know "The Points $F, A, P,B$ form one harmonic quadruple". Also, the RHS in your equation below states "By geobson". There's no user on this site with that username, and a Google search only comes up with several people with that surname, as well as the company "Geobson Resources International". If you don't mind, I'd appreciate an explanation what that means, as well as how you determined the points form a harmonic quadruple. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I posted the quadruple harmonic theory. Geobson is a friend who solved the question but he is not on the forum

Answer (score 1):

Set up coordinate system, with origin at $O$, then we have $F(-4,0), P(-1,0)$.

Let angle $\angle NOB=\theta$, and radius is $r$. So we have $N(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, and the line equation for $NL$

$$y-r\sin\theta=-\frac{1}{\tan\theta}(x-r\cos\theta)$$

We get the coordinate for point $L$

$$L\left(-1, r\sin\theta-\frac{1}{\tan\theta}(-1-r\cos\theta)\right)\Rightarrow L\left(-1, \frac{r+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)$$

Slope for line $OL$

$$k_{OL}=-\frac{r+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

Slope for line $FN$

$$k_{FN}=\frac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta+4}$$

$OL\perp FN\Rightarrow k_{OL}\cdot k_{FN}=-1$, so we get

$$\frac{r+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\cdot\frac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta+4}=1$$
Simplify and we get
$$\Rightarrow r^2\sin\theta=4\sin\theta$$

Cancel the $\sin\theta$ term, we get

$$r=2$$

Comment: Thanks for help but I need a soution by geometry plan

Answer (score 1):

The Points $F, A, P,B$ form one harmonic quadruple
$\therefore \frac{FA}{AP} = \frac{FB}{PB} \implies \frac{4-R}{R-1}=\frac{4+R}{R+1}\\
4R+4-R^2-R =4R-4+R^2-R \implies R^2=4 \therefore \boxed{R=2}$

(Answer by geobson)

[image]